# open msg td on click event with slideup and slidedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open a another `<tr>` tag when first `<tr>` is click.
The code is :

```
<tr class="msg_inner">
  <td><label>some text</label></td>
   <tr id="full_msg" style="display:none">
       <td><label>Hey There.....</label></td>
   </tr>
</tr>
```

script

```
$('.msg_inner').click(function(){
        $('#full_msg_'+no+'').toggle("slow");
});
```

it display block but all is open at same time. I want to display that block after `<tr>` is click.

Comment: `<tr>` elements cannot be the direct children of other `<tr>` elements.

Comment: `$(this).next().toggle("slow");`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use another `<tr>`.
Just add a `<div>` in your td and simply show him like that

**HTML :**

```
<table>
<tr class="line">
<td>
  Hi there !!
  <div class="detail">
  More info here...
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="line">
<td>
  Hi there !
  <div class="detail">
  More info here...
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="line">
<td>
  Hi there !
  <div class="detail">
  More info here...
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.detail{
  display:none;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".line").click(function(){
$(this).find(".detail").toggle();
});
```

[Working Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/27s7ds5w/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
var x=0;
$(".line").click(function(){

if((x%2)==0)
{
 $(this).find(".detail").show();
}
else
{
  $(this).find(".detail").hide();
}
x++;
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/27s7ds5w/1/)

**Or**

Toogle Method

```
$(".line").click(function(){
$(this).find(".detail").toggle(1000);
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/27s7ds5w/2/)

Comment: Why do that when you can use toggle ?